# Ninject MVC: Adding new binding after CreateKernel method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I am using MVC 3 with Ninject. I am defining all of my bindings within Global.asax.cs (a NinjectHttpApplication), in the CreateKernel method.

I also have an HTTP module that runs for all page requests.  The module runs its logic on the PreRequestHandlerExecute after the CreateKernel method is already executed.

I would like to have the HTTP Module define a new binding by linking a class type to a specific instance variable that the module is responsible for constructing. Is this possible?

Basically, in the HttpModule, I am trying to run this:

```
IUserContext userContext = userContextManager.GetUserContext();
Kernel.Bind<IUserContext>().ToConstant(userContext).InRequestScope();
```

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/02/dependency-injection-with-asp-net-httpmodules.aspx

Comment: That shows how to inject things INTO HTTP modules. My question deals with how to bind things FROM http modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be rebinding per-request - if you have 1000 requests in progress at a time, while it's possible to have Ninject manage those registrations (e.g. via `.Named` Bindings using the Binding Metadata facilities), you're abusing the container for something it's not supposed to do (for a start, are you going to do lots of busywork making the `HttpModule` remove the registration after each request? All this is going to do is cause contention as the threads compete for access to the Kernel.

Your `HttpModule` instead should stash the relevant info somewhere suitable (`HttpContext.Items` is generally appropriate, but you might have a better idea?) and then use `ToMethod()` instead to define a single callback that can retrieve the relevant data that has been stashed when a given request needs to use the info your `HttpModule` has stashed.

Something like:

```
Kernel.Bind<IUserContext>()
    .ToMethod( ctx=>(IUserContext)HttpContext.Items["userContext"] )
    .InRequestScope();
```